# Magento 2 Layered Navigation custom attribute with multiselect not showing In filter

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I created a new product attribute named, 'decade', which is multiple select filter. Each product has zero or more than 1 options to select. I changed it to be 'searchable' and 'use in navigation search (with result)'. But this filter just doesn't show up in the navigation filter section.

I run a script to obtain all available filters for the category which contains all the product with the attribute assigned. And I got following, I wonder what causes the count always be 0. I did run reindex and still no luck.

```json
{
  "availablefilter": {
    "Price": [
      {
        "display": "$0.00 - $99.99",
        "value": "-100",
        "count": "645"
      },
      {
        "display": "$100.00 and above",
        "value": "100-",
        "count": "1"
      }
    ],
    "Decade": [
      {
        "display": "1910s",
        "value": "5459",
        "count": 0
      },
      {
        "display": "1920s",
        "value": "5460",
        "count": 0
      },
      {
        "display": "1930s",
        "value": "5461",
        "count": 0
      },
      {
        "display": "1940s",
        "value": "5462",
        "count": 0
      },
      {
        "display": "1950s",
        "value": "5463",
        "count": 0
      },
      {
        "display": "1960s",
        "value": "5464",
        "count": 0
      },
      {
        "display": "1970s",
        "value": "5465",
        "count": 0
      },
      {
        "display": "1980s",
        "value": "5466",
        "count": 0
      },
      {
        "display": "1990s",
        "value": "5467",
        "count": 0
      },
      {
        "display": "2000s",
        "value": "5468",
        "count": 0
      },
      {
        "display": "2010s",
        "value": "5469",
        "count": 0
      }
    ],
    "Rating": [
      {
        "display": "$0.00 - $99.99",
        "value": "-100",
        "count": "645"
      },
      {
        "display": "$100.00 and above",
        "value": "100-",
        "count": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options

```
Use In Layered Navigation

Use In Search Results Layered Navigation
```

Make sure they are enabled.

Also try `Filterable (no results)`

Will have to index after changing settings

Also double check decade values are saved for the product under the store scope you are using.

If you are using only one store toggle single store mode if you are not using that already. That simplifies things.

Comment: I configured the attribute with setting you mentioned and count is still 0. That's the reason the filter will not show up. No product associating any option will lead the filter to be silent.

Answer (score 1):

I provide what I found for other people who have the same issue.

After several hours' struggle, I fixed it by changing the `backend_type` of the attribute from `'text'` to `'varchar'` and re-index. The `'decade'` filter are showing again.

**`Note:`** Don't forget to copy `catalog_product_entity_text's` value over to `catalog_producut_entity_varchar`.